# PHPUnit method invocation assertion failing for abstract class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, abstract-class

I am getting a mock for an abstract class and am using `expects` to verify a specific method is called twice with some particular values. This assertion is failing, even though the production code is correct. This is when I use the `getMockForAbstractClass` method to create the mock. Now when I create a concrete derivative of this abstract class, and feed that into `getMock`, it does work. That approach is however not nice, so I want to know if I can avoid it.

First attempt, using `getMockForAbstractClass` that does not work: http://pastebin.com/09n92Q6h

Second attempt, using a concrete derivative, that does work: http://pastebin.com/SxxgN5Cw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of `ocramius` I found that the concrete methods of abstract classes do not get mocked out by default. One needs to specify the concrete methods that need to be mocked in `getMockForAbstractClass`.

```
private function getMockedAbstractClass($className, array $methods)
{
    return $this->getMockForAbstractClass(
        $className,
        array(),
        '',
        true,
        true,
        true,
        $methods
    );
}
```

Using the mock builder interface for this is somewhat nicer:

```
    $platform = $this->getMockBuilder($className)
        ->setMethods($methods)
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();
```

The full solution can be seen here: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/586/files